# Windows Vista “Could not open input file”

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-vista

I get this strange error when I try to run a php file from anywhere in the system:

```
Could not open input file: drush.php.
```

...except for its own directory. When I try invoke it from its own directory, no problem -- everything works!

Is there a permissions issue here? I looked under security tab in the properties for the file, but every user was given all the permissions that are available.

So I don't get why Windows is not able to open this file from any other directory except where it is located.

Comment: Is the .php file you're trying to run actually called drush.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a "working directory" issue. Have you tried making a shortcut to it on the desktop, then right-click, properties, and change "start in" to the folder where the php file is?

Comment: yeah, that worked. so what do you think i should do? keep using the shortcut rather than the batch file? --  i dont know if i mentioned that the file is being invoked by drush.bat.

Comment: You could use the shortcut or edit the batch file to do "cd c:\yourpath" before it runs that command. You might also want to try t the PATH comment below to see if that does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

the file drush.bat from the php folder contains:

```
@php.exe "%~dp0drush.php" --php="php.exe" %*
```

I replaced it with

```
@php.exe "%~dp0/PEAR/drush/drush.php" --php="php.exe" %*
```

the actual path to the drush.php was not directly in the php folder, it was in php/PEAR/drush

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the path of the PHP bin folder to your %PATH% [environmental variable](http://vistaonwindows.com/environment_variables.html)

Usually in C:\Program Files\PHP\bin (or C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\bin) or C:\PHP\bin

Comment: actually i tried that. it didn't work. same error.